# how to print the else statement in view

Tags: codeigniter

I want to print "No records found" in view

---

```
public function getProductsListByCategory4($limit, $start) 
{                       
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('image_path,tagline,category_id,product_id');
    $this->db->where('category_id','4');
    $query = $this->db->get("tb1_bl_products order by tagline");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'No records found';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using this code in model.

Improve your code in model as below:

```
public function getProductsListByCategory4($limit, $start) 
{                       
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('image_path,tagline,category_id,product_id');
    $this->db->where('category_id','4');
    $query = $this->db->get("tb1_bl_products order by tagline");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result_array(); // single line which removes for loop
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
$data["records"] = $this->MODEL_NAME->getProductsListByCategory4($limit, $start);
$this->load->view("VIEW_FILE",$data);
```

In your view,

```
if(count($records)>0)
{
   foreach($records as $r)
   {
       echo $r["FIELD_NAME"];
   }
}
else
{
  echo "<p>No Records found</p>";
}
```

Comment: in the model structure I would return FALSE or NULL instead of empty array() I find it more helpfull so in view/controller I can just `if ($tmp = $this->model->function($param)) {$tmp has some value} else { $tmp is FALSE}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getProductsListByCategory4($limit, $start) 
{                           
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('image_path,tagline,category_id,product_id');
    $this->db->where('category_id','4');
    $query = $this->db->get("tb1_bl_products order by tagline");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {

        $data = '';
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Then check on your VIEW if the `$data` is empty then display 'No records found'

Comment: why would you ever set variable so you can return it? why not just simple `return '';` ? There is no appending happening so `$data` is not used in else statement.

Answer (score 0):

just use count in this way :-

```
public function getProductsListByCategory4($limit, $start) 
{     
    $data=array();                  
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('image_path,tagline,category_id,product_id');
    $this->db->where('category_id','4');
    $query = $this->db->get("tb1_bl_products order by tagline");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $data;
 }
```

In View :-

```
if(count($data)){
   // do your stuff here
}
else{
 echo 'No records found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

every other answer here uses `count()` which is not bad at all but I find it a waste.

I find this to be most efficient way to do this

**model**

```
...
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { //using count here!

        return $query->result_array(); // or result() if you want array of objects

    } else {

        return FALSE;

    }
...
```

**controller** //exactly as kumar_v answer

```
if ($data['product_list'] = $this->model->model_method($param, $param2)) {
    //if model returns FALSE this code is jumped over
    $this->load->view('view_file_no_data');
} else {
    //all good we have some data to show load
    $this->load->view('view_file', $data);
}
```

**view_file**

```
// no need for checking if there are some data or not
foreach($product_list as $key => $product) {
    echo $product['image_path'];
}
```

**view_file_no_data**

```
echo "no results";
```

> I split views just for this example, normally you make one view and
>   make an `if/else`.